# Run a Big Query Schedule everytime a table is updated

Tags: google-bigquery

So I have this schedule that gets data from some tables and aggregate then into a single table, that I use as a source in a data studio dash, one of these tables (table 1), is updated daily, sometimes more than once, I wanted to know if there is a way to automatically run the schedule every time this table (table1) is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, BigQuery scheduled queries need the parameters of run_time and run_date, so if you want this to be only with BigQuery, you can schedule multiple queries at different times.

Additionally, using a trigger in BigQuery is not possible because this is unsupported.

I recommend you to use a [Cloud Run Action](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/how-trigger-cloud-run-actions-bigquery-events) that gets the event after any Insert and this creates an event Trigger, so this could do what you are looking for, but without any scheduled queries.